# How to create SharePoint page layout based on existing .aspx file

Tags: 2013, page-layout, publishing-page

I have an existing page layout that I want to slightly modify and use. When I upload the modified file to a pages library it works fine but I would like to be able to select that page as a layout going forward, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of uploading the page to `page library` you should upload it to `Master pages and page layouts` by going to

> Root Site > Site Settings > Web Designer Galleries > Master pages and page layouts

Or navigate directly to

```
http://SiteCollectionURL/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx
```

**Note :** Not all ASPX files considered as a page layout so you should make sure that it's a page layout page as you mentioned in your question.